# Shading with multiple plots using Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I would like to replicate the [figure](https://lectures.quantecon.org/_images/arellano_time_series.png) using [`Plots.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaPlots/Plots.jl).

However, I have two problems

- I do not know how to shade certain period of the figure
- I want to draw multiple plots as the example

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can get you started:

```
using Plots

subplots = 3
time = 250
shade_xlims = [125,140]
data_matrix = Plots.fakedata(time, subplots)

p = plot(data_matrix, layout=(subplots,1), xlabel = "time");
for i in 1:subplots
   ymin,ymax = extrema(data_matrix[:,i]) # determine ylims for shade
   plot!(p[i],                    # apply shade to each subplot
         shade_xlims,             # xlims for shade
         [0,0],                   # dummy y coordinates
         fillrange = (ymin,ymax), # apply ylims
         fillalpha = 0.5,         # set transparency
         fillcolor=:gray,         # set shade color
         label = "")              # avoid shade labels
end
p # show the final graph
```

Cheers!